# Sorting array from Firebase fails

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, sorting, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get an array of users sorted by the number of their likes. I am getting the user from a Firebase database, in case this changes things.

User example:

```
{
    "likes": [
        {
            "createDate": {
                "date": 22,
                "day": 3,
                "hours": 10,
                "minutes": 33,
                "month": 7,
                "seconds": 25,
                "time": 1534934005660,
                "timezoneOffset": 0,
                "year": 118
            },
            "creatorID": "1OA4U39rsPPXZblWG6nLHObB7gz1",
            "firebaseKey": "-LKWBYQFbaO1Fs8_Rllc",
            "workID": "-LK6-jxPZ0tCNW6c-GTI",
            "id": "0"
        },
        {
            "createDate": {
                "date": 22,
                "day": 3,
                "hours": 13,
                "minutes": 45,
                "month": 7,
                "seconds": 50,
                "time": 1534938350990,
                "timezoneOffset": -120,
                "year": 118
            },
            "creatorID": "8Z7dd5L01FW0EbV0Wvu1KaXfmOx1",
            "firebaseKey": "-LKWS7ZsUu2Khn0j7vLk",
            "workID": "-LK5xZaui7IIcJcT22Rp",
            "id": "1"
        }
    ],
}
```

I was trying to use the `sort` method like this, but no luck.

```
var solversByLikes = solvers.sort((a, b) => a.likes.length - b.likes.length);
```

I am testing it by then console logging the `solversByLikes` array. This is the result:

```
0 LikesComponent.js:46
0 LikesComponent.js:46
0 LikesComponent.js:46
0 LikesComponent.js:46
2 LikesComponent.js:46
2 LikesComponent.js:46
```

But if I switch the a, and b, so that the sorting should be reversed, nothing changes.

```
var solversByLikes = solvers.sort((a, b) => b.likes.length - a.likes.length);
```

I tried replicating the issue like this:

```js
allUsers = [{likes: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}, {likes: [1, 2,]}, {likes: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,]}, {likes: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,]}, {likes: [1, 2, 3, 4,]}, {likes: [1, 2, 3]}]

solversByLikes = allUsers.sort((a, b) => b.likes.length - a.likes.length);

solversByLikes.forEach(user => console.log(user.likes.length));
```

But this works as intended...

Any idea how to make it sort?

I'm not getting any error or anything.

Comment: What is your expected output look like?

Comment: Well I'd like the users to be sorted by the number of likes, biggest to smallest

Comment: try to use jslinq library

Comment: @MuruGan do you mind broadening your comment? How is jslinq supposed to help with sorting?

Comment: Okay wait. Lemme give you an answer with jsfiddle